# lxml xpath doesn't ignore "&nbsp;"

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have this HTML:

```
<td class="0">
<b>Bold Text</b>&nbsp;
<a href=""></a>
</td>

<td class="0">
Regular Text&nbsp;
<a href=""></a>
</td>
```

Which, when formatted with xpath...

```
new_html = tree.xpath('//td[@class="0"]/text() | //td[@class="0"]/b/text()')
```

Prints:

```
['Bold Text', '', 'Regular Text']
```

As you can see, the `&nbsp;` character hasn't been ignored and is actually read as an extra entry in td. How can I get a better output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, I'd iterate over all the desired `td` elements and get the [`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods):

```
[td.text_content().strip() for td in tree.xpath('//td[@class="0"]')]
```

Prints:

```
[u'Bold Text', u'Regular Text']
```

Answer (score 11):

**Note:** I'm posting this not so much as an answer, but as an interesting thing (I did not know) about [XPath's `normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space). This might help other users.

It looks like `normalize-space()` which I would have suggested here, does not remove `'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)`

```
>>> text = '''<html>
... <table>
... <tr>
... <td class="0">
... <b>Bold Text</b>&nbsp;
... <a href=""></a>
... </td>
... 
... <td class="0">
... Regular Text&nbsp;
... <a href=""></a>
... </td>
... </tr>
... </table>
... </html>'''
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
>>>
>>> # ouch, &nbsp; is not stripped...
>>> [td.xpath('normalize-space(.)') for td in doc.xpath('.//td[@class="0"]')]
[u'Bold Text\xa0', u'Regular Text\xa0']
>>>
>>> # one needs to strip() like in @alecxe's answer
>>> [td.xpath('normalize-space(.)').strip() for td in doc.xpath('.//td[@class="0"]')]
[u'Bold Text', u'Regular Text']
>>>
```

---

Edit:

So I continued looking into whitespace characters and how they are stripped or not using Python's `strip()` or XPath's `normalize-space()`.

The following is a bit longer than I first wanted, but he's the whole script to test Unicode whitespace codepoints:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> whitespace_chars_wikipedia = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode'
>>> r = requests.get(whitespace_chars_wikipedia)
>>> 
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import collections
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> WhitespaceChar = collections.namedtuple('WhitespaceChar', ['codepoint', 'name', 'decimal', 'named_entity'])
>>> r = re.compile('')
>>> wchars = {}
>>> for table in doc.xpath('''
...     .//div[@class="NavHead"][.//strong="Whitespace"]
...       /following-sibling::div[@class="NavContent"]
...           //table[1] 
...     |
...     .//table[caption="Related characters"]
...     '''):
...     for row in table.xpath('.//tr[position()>1]'):
...         codepoint = row.xpath('string(./td[1]/text()[last()])')
...         name = row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[2])').upper()
...         decimal = int(row.xpath('string(./td[3])'))
...         named_entity = row.xpath('''string(
...             ./td[last()]/text()[contains(., "HTML/XML named entity: ")]
...                         /following-sibling::code
...             )''')
...         wchars[decimal] = WhitespaceChar(codepoint, name, decimal, named_entity or None)
... 
>>> 
>>> listitems = "\n".join(
...     '<li><i>&#x{wchar.decimal:04X};</i> <b data-decimal="{wchar.decimal}">{wchar.codepoint}</b> <i>&#x{wchar.decimal:04X};</i></li>'.format(wchar=c)
...     for c in sorted(wchars.values(), key=lambda c: c.decimal)
... )
>>> text = '''
... <html>
...     <body>
...         <ul>
... {}
...         </ul>
...     </body>
... </html>
... '''.format(listitems)
>>> print text

<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
<li><i>&#x0009;</i> <b data-decimal="9">U+0009</b> <i>&#x0009;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x000A;</i> <b data-decimal="10">U+000A</b> <i>&#x000A;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x000B;</i> <b data-decimal="11">U+000B</b> <i>&#x000B;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x000C;</i> <b data-decimal="12">U+000C</b> <i>&#x000C;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x000D;</i> <b data-decimal="13">U+000D</b> <i>&#x000D;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x0020;</i> <b data-decimal="32">U+0020</b> <i>&#x0020;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x0085;</i> <b data-decimal="133">U+0085</b> <i>&#x0085;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x00A0;</i> <b data-decimal="160">U+00A0</b> <i>&#x00A0;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x1680;</i> <b data-decimal="5760">U+1680</b> <i>&#x1680;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x180E;</i> <b data-decimal="6158">U+180E</b> <i>&#x180E;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2000;</i> <b data-decimal="8192">U+2000</b> <i>&#x2000;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2001;</i> <b data-decimal="8193">U+2001</b> <i>&#x2001;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2002;</i> <b data-decimal="8194">U+2002</b> <i>&#x2002;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2003;</i> <b data-decimal="8195">U+2003</b> <i>&#x2003;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2004;</i> <b data-decimal="8196">U+2004</b> <i>&#x2004;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2005;</i> <b data-decimal="8197">U+2005</b> <i>&#x2005;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2006;</i> <b data-decimal="8198">U+2006</b> <i>&#x2006;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2007;</i> <b data-decimal="8199">U+2007</b> <i>&#x2007;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2008;</i> <b data-decimal="8200">U+2008</b> <i>&#x2008;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2009;</i> <b data-decimal="8201">U+2009</b> <i>&#x2009;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x200A;</i> <b data-decimal="8202">U+200A</b> <i>&#x200A;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x200B;</i> <b data-decimal="8203">U+200B</b> <i>&#x200B;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x200C;</i> <b data-decimal="8204">U+200C</b> <i>&#x200C;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x200D;</i> <b data-decimal="8205">U+200D</b> <i>&#x200D;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2028;</i> <b data-decimal="8232">U+2028</b> <i>&#x2028;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2029;</i> <b data-decimal="8233">U+2029</b> <i>&#x2029;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x202F;</i> <b data-decimal="8239">U+202F</b> <i>&#x202F;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x205F;</i> <b data-decimal="8287">U+205F</b> <i>&#x205F;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x2060;</i> <b data-decimal="8288">U+2060</b> <i>&#x2060;</i></li>
<li><i>&#x3000;</i> <b data-decimal="12288">U+3000</b> <i>&#x3000;</i></li>
<li><i>&#xFEFF;</i> <b data-decimal="65279">U+FEFF</b> <i>&#xFEFF;</i></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>

>>> 
>>> 
>>> doc2 = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
>>> 
>>> from prettytable import PrettyTable
>>> 
>>> x = PrettyTable([
...         #"#",
...         #"Code point", 
...         "Name", 
...         #"Char Python repr", 
...         "Test string", 
...         "strip()", 
...         "normalize-space()"
...     ])
>>> 
>>> for cnt, li in enumerate(doc2.xpath('.//ul/li'), start=1):
...     codepoint = li.xpath('string(b)')
...     wc = wchars[li.xpath('number(b/@data-decimal)')]
...     tstring = li.xpath('string(.)')
...     x.add_row([
...             #cnt,
...             #wc.codepoint,
...             wc.name,
...             #repr([unichr(wc.decimal)]).strip('[]'),
...             repr([tstring]).strip('[]'),
...             tstring.strip() == codepoint,
...             li.xpath('normalize-space(.)') == codepoint
...         ])
...
```

Do `strip()` and `normalize-space()` strip these whitespace characters?

```
>>> print x
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------+
|              Name             |       Test string       | strip() | normalize-space() |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------+
|      CHARACTER TABULATION     |      '\t U+0009 \t'     |   True  |        True       |
|           LINE FEED           |      '\n U+000A \n'     |   True  |        True       |
|        LINE TABULATION        |        ' U+000B '       |   True  |        True       |
|           FORM FEED           |        ' U+000C '       |   True  |        True       |
|        CARRIAGE RETURN        |      '\r U+000D \r'     |   True  |        True       |
|             SPACE             |       '  U+0020  '      |   True  |        True       |
|           NEXT LINE           |   u'\x85 U+0085 \x85'   |   True  |       False       |
|         NO-BREAK SPACE        |   u'\xa0 U+00A0 \xa0'   |   True  |       False       |
|        OGHAM SPACE MARK       | u'\u1680 U+1680 \u1680' |   True  |       False       |
|   MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR   | u'\u180e U+180E \u180e' |   True  |       False       |
|            EN QUAD            | u'\u2000 U+2000 \u2000' |   True  |       False       |
|            EM QUAD            | u'\u2001 U+2001 \u2001' |   True  |       False       |
|            EN SPACE           | u'\u2002 U+2002 \u2002' |   True  |       False       |
|            EM SPACE           | u'\u2003 U+2003 \u2003' |   True  |       False       |
|       THREE-PER-EM SPACE      | u'\u2004 U+2004 \u2004' |   True  |       False       |
|       FOUR-PER-EM SPACE       | u'\u2005 U+2005 \u2005' |   True  |       False       |
|        SIX-PER-EM SPACE       | u'\u2006 U+2006 \u2006' |   True  |       False       |
|          FIGURE SPACE         | u'\u2007 U+2007 \u2007' |   True  |       False       |
|       PUNCTUATION SPACE       | u'\u2008 U+2008 \u2008' |   True  |       False       |
|           THIN SPACE          | u'\u2009 U+2009 \u2009' |   True  |       False       |
|           HAIR SPACE          | u'\u200a U+200A \u200a' |   True  |       False       |
|        ZERO WIDTH SPACE       | u'\u200b U+200B \u200b' |  False  |       False       |
|     ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER     | u'\u200c U+200C \u200c' |  False  |       False       |
|       ZERO WIDTH JOINER       | u'\u200d U+200D \u200d' |  False  |       False       |
|         LINE SEPARATOR        | u'\u2028 U+2028 \u2028' |   True  |       False       |
|      PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR      | u'\u2029 U+2029 \u2029' |   True  |       False       |
|     NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE     | u'\u202f U+202F \u202f' |   True  |       False       |
|   MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE   | u'\u205f U+205F \u205f' |   True  |       False       |
|          WORD JOINER          | u'\u2060 U+2060 \u2060' |  False  |       False       |
|       IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE       | u'\u3000 U+3000 \u3000' |   True  |       False       |
| ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE | u'\ufeff U+FEFF \ufeff' |  False  |       False       |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------+
>>>
```

Whitespace chars:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(wchars)
{9: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+0009', name='CHARACTER TABULATION', decimal=9, named_entity=None),
 10: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+000A', name='LINE FEED', decimal=10, named_entity='&NewLine;'),
 11: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+000B', name='LINE TABULATION', decimal=11, named_entity=None),
 12: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+000C', name='FORM FEED', decimal=12, named_entity=None),
 13: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+000D', name='CARRIAGE RETURN', decimal=13, named_entity=None),
 32: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+0020', name='SPACE', decimal=32, named_entity=None),
 133: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+0085', name='NEXT LINE', decimal=133, named_entity=None),
 160: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+00A0', name='NO-BREAK SPACE', decimal=160, named_entity='&nbsp;'),
 5760: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+1680', name='OGHAM SPACE MARK', decimal=5760, named_entity=None),
 6158: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+180E', name='MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR', decimal=6158, named_entity=None),
 8192: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2000', name='EN QUAD', decimal=8192, named_entity=None),
 8193: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2001', name='EM QUAD', decimal=8193, named_entity=None),
 8194: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2002', name='EN SPACE', decimal=8194, named_entity='&ensp;'),
 8195: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2003', name='EM SPACE', decimal=8195, named_entity='&emsp;'),
 8196: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2004', name='THREE-PER-EM SPACE', decimal=8196, named_entity='&emsp13;'),
 8197: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2005', name='FOUR-PER-EM SPACE', decimal=8197, named_entity='&emsp14;'),
 8198: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2006', name='SIX-PER-EM SPACE', decimal=8198, named_entity=None),
 8199: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2007', name='FIGURE SPACE', decimal=8199, named_entity='&numsp;'),
 8200: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2008', name='PUNCTUATION SPACE', decimal=8200, named_entity='&puncsp;'),
 8201: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2009', name='THIN SPACE', decimal=8201, named_entity='&thinsp;'),
 8202: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+200A', name='HAIR SPACE', decimal=8202, named_entity='&hairsp;'),
 8203: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+200B', name='ZERO WIDTH SPACE', decimal=8203, named_entity=None),
 8204: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+200C', name='ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER', decimal=8204, named_entity='&zwnj;'),
 8205: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+200D', name='ZERO WIDTH JOINER', decimal=8205, named_entity='&zwj;'),
 8232: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2028', name='LINE SEPARATOR', decimal=8232, named_entity=None),
 8233: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2029', name='PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR', decimal=8233, named_entity=None),
 8239: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+202F', name='NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE', decimal=8239, named_entity=None),
 8287: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+205F', name='MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE', decimal=8287, named_entity='&MediumSpace;'),
 8288: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+2060', name='WORD JOINER', decimal=8288, named_entity='&NoBreak;'),
 12288: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+3000', name='IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE', decimal=12288, named_entity=None),
 65279: WhitespaceChar(codepoint='U+FEFF', name='ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE', decimal=65279, named_entity=None)}
>>>
```