# Scrapy : Select tag with non-breaking space with xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

In my scrapy spider, i want to select only `<p>` with text content :

```
item['Description'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="textepresentation"]//p[string(.)]').extract()
```

It works fine, but unfortunately, doing this, i also get empty `<p>` with non-breaking space

```
u'<p>\xa0</p>',
```

How to avoid selecting `<p>` with non-breaking space with xpath ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XPath's `normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) string function for this with a couple of predicates:

- `[normalize-space()]` so that you get elements with non-empty string representation, excluding leading and trailing whitespace
- `[not(contains(normalize-space(), "\u00a0"))]` because `NO-BREAK SPACE` is not removed (see [this other answer where I checked which ones work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829869), you may want to add other characters to test)

Sample:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=u'''
... <html>
...     <p>&nbsp;</p>
...     <p>something</p>
...     <p>  </p>
...     <p><a href="http://example.com">some link</a></p>
... </html>
... ''')
>>> selector.xpath(u'''
...     //p[normalize-space()]
...        [not(contains(normalize-space(), "\u00a0"))]
... ''').extract()
[u'<p>something</p>', u'<p><a href="http://example.com">some link</a></p>']
>>>
```

---

Edit:

following on the of @Kimmy's answer, here's an alternative with 1 predicate, for other whitespace characters as well:

- take whitespace characters that are not replace by `normalize-space()`
- and put them in an XPath `translate()` call with ' '
- normalize the spaces, trimming leading and trailing ones

Here it goes:

```
>>> chars = '''
... #CHARACTER TABULATION
... #LINE FEED
... #LINE TABULATION
... #FORM FEED
... #CARRIAGE RETURN
... #SPACE
... #NEXT LINE
... NO-BREAK SPACE
... OGHAM SPACE MARK
... MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
... EN QUAD
... EM QUAD
... EN SPACE
... EM SPACE
... THREE-PER-EM SPACE
... FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
... SIX-PER-EM SPACE
... FIGURE SPACE
... PUNCTUATION SPACE
... THIN SPACE
... HAIR SPACE
... ZERO WIDTH SPACE
... ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
... ZERO WIDTH JOINER
... LINE SEPARATOR
... PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
... NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
... MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
... WORD JOINER
... IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
... ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
... '''
>>> import unicodedata
>>> wsp = [unicodedata.lookup(c)
...        for c in chars.splitlines()
...        if c.strip() and not c.startswith('#')]
>>> 
>>> # somehow NEXT LINE (U+0085) does not work with unicodedata
... wsp.append(u'\u0085')
>>> 
>>> selector.xpath(u'''
...     //p[normalize-space(translate(., "%(in)s", "%(out)s"))]
...     ''' % {'in': ''.join(wsp),
...            'out': ' '*len(wsp)
...     }).extract()
[u'<p>something</p>', u'<p><a href="http://example.com">some link</a></p>']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for this valuable detailed explanation ! It works as expected. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
//p[translate(string(.),"\xa0","")]
```

Comment: Nice try, but `item['Description'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="textepresentation"]//p[translate(string(.),'\xa0','')]').extract()
                                                                                                                  SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: @jacquesseite String delimiter conflict. Consistently use double-quotes in your XPath expression i.e `translate(string(.),"\xa0","")`

Comment: Edited to use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @har07 This time `ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters`  Trying to figure out...