# Remove/Exclude Non-Breaking Space from Scrapy result

Tags: python, scrapy

I am currently trying to scrape a website for article prices but I have run into a problem (after having somehow solved the problem that the prices were dynamically generated, which was a huge pain).

I am able to receive the prices and the article names without a problem, but every second result for 'price' is "\xa0". I have tried removing it using 'normalize-space()' but to no avail.

My code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from horni.items import HorniItem

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "placeholder"
    allowed_domains = ["placeholder.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.placeholder.com"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get("https://www.placeholder.com")
        response = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        for post in response.xpath('//body'):
            item = myItem()
            item['article_name'] = post.xpath('//a[@class="title-link"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['price'] = post.xpath('//p[@class="display-price"]/span]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: If you're interested, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33829869/2572383 looks at the various whitespace characters and how you can or cannot strip them with XPath `normalize-space()` and/or Python's `strip()`

Comment: can you show an HTML snippet over which you apply `//p[@class="display-price"]/span]/text()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\xa0` is a non-breaking space in Latin1. Replace it like this:

```
string = string.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

*Update:*

You can apply the code as following:

```
for post in response.xpath('//body'):
    item = myItem()
    item['article_name'] = post.xpath('//a[@class="title-link"]/span/text()').extract()
    item['price'] = post.xpath('//p[@class="display-price"]/span]/text()').extract()
    item['price'] = item['price'].replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
    if(item['price'].strip()):
        yield item
```

In here you replace the char and then only yield the item if the price is not empty.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, I'm not sure I understand how to do this. Can I apply your code to my `item['price']`? Or is there a way to exclude the non-breaking spaces from the Scrapy response alltogether?

Comment: Thanks for your help. `if(item['price'].strip()):` did not work for me, as the element is a list. However you nudged me in the right direction.  I used `x for x in item['prices'] if x != u'\xa0'`.

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction. If your code works now then everything is fine :)